# Is there a proposed CSS3 “soft floating” property?

Tags: html, css, element, css-float

Does anyone have any idea if there is anything planned in the html5 or CSS3 spec regarding the floating of elements.

I titled this question "soft floating" as I'm interested in the idea of giving a group of elements css properties something like the following...

imagine if you will a styled list of images...

```
<ul>
<li><img src='1.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='2.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='3.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='4.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='5.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='6.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='7.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='8.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='9.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

and styled with:-

```
ul{
list-style:none;
}
li{
float:left;
}
```

imagine the images are of fairly random heights, say between 50 and 100 pixels high.

Currently floating these left might result in one or more of the images snagging, resulting in the rest of the floats also being out of place ( visually, but not actually wrong as far as browser rendering is concerned).

I'm wondering if there might be any kind of proposal or attribute for some kind of "soft floating" whereby elements pushed out by the right hand extent of the floated element(s) container would be effectively carriage returned/cleared past the bottom edge of all preceeding floated elements.

Wow. Does any of that make any sense whatsoever...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you’re on about.

I think your desired layout is already achieved by `display: inline-block`. See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/6eh23/

If that’s not what you were going for, then as far as I know, there aren’t any proposals along these lines.

However, I don’t follow the new specs very closely. If there were something like this, I think it would be in one of the following CSS3 modules:

- [Template Layout](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs#layout)
- [Grid Positioning](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs#grid)
- [Flexible Box Layout](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs#flexbox)

You can browse through the other specs-in-progress on the CSS “Current Work” page:

- http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Comment: Wow. haha.... Thats great paul. I'd been steering clear of inline-block for quite a while as I'm sure I experienced problems with it in IE/FF, or FF/IE styling a couple of years ago, but never thought about using it in this context. Tested it and it seem to work across both browsers anyway, in jsfiddle. Well done with that elegant solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: Oh yeah... http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html   inline-block is an issue with IE<=7. Knew there was something nagging at the back of my head about this solution. Still though, I did phrase the question in the context of html5, and that's due in 2014 so I guess support for those versions of ie should be minimal by then. cheers again.

Comment: @BizNuge: Firefox didn’t support `inline-block` at all until Firefox 3. IE 6 only supports it either on elements that are inline by default, or block by default, and I can never remember which (I think inline?), so you’re entirely right there are issues with older browsers.

Comment: @BizNuge: with regard to specs, HTML5 is here now, although [it’s moving away from versions and is just HTML now](http://blog.whatwg.org/html-is-the-new-html5). CSS3 is made up of [modules, each with their own version](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/#whymods), and each module is “due” pretty much when it’s done. Web standards are more codifications of common browser behaviour than specs for browsers to follow.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - About html5 being here now. I realise there's a lot of the spec available to us as developers now, but I was more thinking into the future with browser deprecation, than in terms of the actual standard to be honest, although my phrasing may well have been off. Cheers for the help and discussion Paul!

Comment: @BizNuge: sure. Browsers don’t go away until people stop using them though, and it’s difficult to guess when that’s going to happen.

Comment: I envisage a future where text and images will be beamed directly into my subconcious from t'internet... when that day comes I'll style it myself thanks!!! ;)

Comment: @BizNuge: and that way, we could stop people using IE6 by beating it out of their heads — extreme, sure, but sooo cathartic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <!-- Images of varying heights -->
    <img src="[location]" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

This will achieve the effect of 'soft floating' (I think). If you require any other HTML other than the images, then you could have issues, depending on the HTML. I reckon you could get away with adding more inline elements, however block elements would break this unless you floated them, raising the original problem.

I think the idea of soft floating would be hard for browsers to calculate, due to the nature of floated elements and how they are supposed to behave. Unless you specified the height of the floated element then IIRC this would only be known at runtime after the element has been rendered? using Javascript to calculate such height/width.

*Typically, I think it is best to know the biggest height of an image that will be used in the page, and set the height of the floated element to that. The same for the width of the element. I'm not sure soft-floating would be a good idea.*

Comment: I have been setting the height of the images to a maximum previously mig, constraining them within an anchor element of explicit height, to get around this issue. Your suggestion of vertical-align combined with Pauls solution seems to be the cherry on the cake really. good suggestion.